# JS Array Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to create a program that will ask the user for numbers until they're done and store that value in a array. Then I need to create another array that's the same as the first array except every third element is double the first array's element pair. Currently getting a syntax error for unexpected bracket at the for loop though I feel as there has to be a better method of going about this then I am.

```
var arr = [ ]; 
var brr = [ ];
var y = arrin(0);

function arrin(x) {

  if (!isNaN(x)) {
  arr.push(x) 
  x = parseInt(prompt("Would you like to enter a number? If not cancel.", "0"), 10);
  y = arrin(x);
  } else {

    for(i in arr, i++){
    if(i % 3 = 2) {
        brr.push(i*2)
    }else{
        brr.push(i)
    }
document.getElementById("a1").innerHTML = arr;
document.getElementById("b1").innerHTML = brr;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `for(i in arr, i++) ` makes no sense See [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and other issue is `i % 3 = 2`

Comment: @epascarello post that as an answer.

Comment: "*where is the syntax error?*". Where you have `for(i in arr, i++)` you should have `for(i in arr)` or (preferably) `for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)`. There also seems to be one to many `}` after `document.getElementById...`.

Comment: You could also visit jshint.com and check for syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is wrong,  you can use `for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){ // Or for(i in arr){` and also the `if(i % 3 = 2)` you are suppose to use as `if(i % 3 == 2)`.

```js
var arr = [];
var brr = [];
var y = arrin(0);

function arrin(x) {
  if (!isNaN(x)) {
    arr.push(x)
    x = parseInt(prompt("Would you like to enter a number? If not cancel.", "0"), 10);
    y = arrin(x);
  } else {

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { // Or for(i in arr){
      if (i % 3 == 2) {
        brr.push(i * 2)
      } else {
        brr.push(i)
      }
      document.getElementById("a1").innerHTML = arr;
      document.getElementById("b1").innerHTML = brr;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="a1">
</div>
<div id="b1">
</div>
```